# Вывести списком значения из одной таблицы связанной с другой таблицей

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть 2 таблицы:
[image: Первая таблица]

[image: Вторая таблица]

*1) Это задачи*
*2) Метки этих задач(Работа, учеба и тд...)*

Стоит задача вывести под каждой меткой весь список задач, как на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу понят, как соединить значения из таблицы todo_item(задачи) и вывести все на одну страницу. Получается только вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знатоки Ruby, помогите, буду благодарен. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Код следует копировать, а не скриншотить. Это и проще, и быстрее, и удобнее. Также был бы более интересен код моделей, а не миграций. Миграции не отвечают за текущую работу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
- TodoList.find_each do |td_list|
    h1
      = td_list.title

    ul
      - td_list.todo_items.find_each do |td_item|
        li
          = td_item.text
```

Также вам необходимо будет ознакомиться со следующей информацией:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association
- И почитайте про правила наименований в Ruby